# Get emails from users by custom field SQL

Tags: custom-field, users, wpdb, user-meta, sql

I'm trying to build an SQL query to retrieve a list of users whose "options_futures" custom field is equal to "Options"

I wrote this query, but is not working:

```
$data = $wpdb->get_results(
'SELECT user_email 
 FROM $wpdb->users 
 LEFT JOIN $wpdb->usermeta WHERE
  options_futures="Options"',
ARRAY_A
);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would do it this way:

```
$args = array(
            'meta_query' => array(
                array(
                    'key' => 'options_futures',
                    'value' => 'Options',
                    'compare' => '='
                )
            )
);
$users = get_users($args);
```

Comment: Hi Picard, thanks for your suggestion, I know this kind of queries, but actually I need to formulate it as an SQL query, to include it as part of a plugin options (Post Status Notifier). Here's the plugin documentation: http://docs.ifeelweb.de/post-status-notifier/dynamic_recipients.html